# Требуется обеспечить корректную работу программу на одноядерном процессоре

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Программа читает файл, содержащий логи веб-сервера, парсит содержимое выводя его в таблицу из четырёх столбцов(доменное имя, url, размер данных, ошибки). В ней содержится ошибка, которая может проявиться при использовании программы на одноядерном процессоре, помогите её определить. Говорят, что ресурс неправильно защищён критической секцией и он использует несколько потоков. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace lab2Form
{
    class ReadList
    {
        public List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    }

    class LogStruct
    {
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> domainName;
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> URL;
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> domainData;
        public Dictionary<string, ulong> errorCodes;

        public LogStruct()
        {
            domainName = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
            URL = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
            domainData = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
            errorCodes = new Dictionary<string, ulong> { };
        }
    }

    class CLogParser
    {
        LogStruct m_logStruct;
        ReadList m_ReadList;

        public CLogParser()
        {
             m_logStruct = new LogStruct();
             m_ReadList = new ReadList(); 
        }

        public void ThreadReadList(object param)
        {
            StreamReader file;
            string line;
            string logName = (string)param;
            try
            {
                file = new StreamReader(logName);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lock (m_ReadList.lst)
                {
                    m_ReadList.lst.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }

        public void ThreadProc()
        {    
            string line;            
            for (var i = 0; i < m_ReadList.lst.Count; i++)                             
            {
                    lock (m_ReadList.lst)
                    {
                        line = m_ReadList.lst[i];
                    }
                    var space_pos = line.IndexOf(' ');
                    if (space_pos > 0)
                    {
                        string[] parameters = line.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        string domainName = parameters[0];
                        bool isMainPage = (parameters[4] == "\"-\"") ? true : false;
                        string relativePageAddress = (isMainPage) ? "/" : parameters[5];
                        Regex reg = new Regex(" \\d+");
                        MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(line);
                        string errorCode = matches[1].Value;
                        ulong pageSize = (matches.Count > 2) ? Convert.ToUInt64(matches[2].Value) : 0;
                        string fullAdress = domainName + relativePageAddress;
                        string fullErrCode = domainName + errorCode;

                        if (m_logStruct.domainName.ContainsKey(domainName))
                        {
                            lock (m_logStruct.domainName)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.domainName[domainName]++;
                            }
                            lock (m_logStruct.domainData)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.domainData[domainName] += pageSize;
                            }
                            lock (m_logStruct.URL)
                            {
                                if (m_logStruct.URL.ContainsKey(fullAdress))///////////////////////////////////
                                {
                                    m_logStruct.URL[fullAdress]++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    m_logStruct.URL.Add(fullAdress, 1);
                                }
                            }
                            if (m_logStruct.errorCodes.ContainsKey(fullErrCode))
                            {
                                lock (m_logStruct.errorCodes)
                                {
                                    m_logStruct.errorCodes[fullErrCode]++;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lock (m_logStruct.errorCodes)
                                {
                                    m_logStruct.errorCodes.Add(fullErrCode, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lock (m_logStruct.domainName)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.domainName.Add(domainName, 1);
                            }
                            lock (m_logStruct.URL)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.domainData.Add(domainName, pageSize);
                            }
                            lock (m_logStruct.domainData)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.URL.Add(fullAdress, 1);
                            }
                            lock (m_logStruct.errorCodes)
                            {
                                m_logStruct.errorCodes.Add(fullErrCode, 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }           
        }

        public void ShowData(ref DataGridView dmRequests, ref DataGridView URL, ref DataGridView dmData, ref DataGridView errorCodes)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> dmReqList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> urlReqList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>(); 
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> dmDataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>> errCodesList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ulong>>();

            lock (m_logStruct.domainName)
            {
                dmReqList = m_logStruct.domainName.ToList();
            }
            lock(m_logStruct.URL)
            {
                urlReqList = m_logStruct.URL.ToList();
            }
            lock(m_logStruct.domainData)
            {
                dmDataList = m_logStruct.domainData.ToList();
            }
            lock(m_logStruct.errorCodes)
            {
                errCodesList = m_logStruct.errorCodes.ToList();
            }

            dmRequests.DataSource = dmReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
            URL.DataSource = urlReqList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
            dmData.DataSource = dmDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
            errorCodes.DataSource = errCodesList.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Андрей Бобков, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему.

Comment: Ох извиняюсь) Совсем забыл..Минуточку.

Comment: Всё, описание появилось

Comment: первый раз вижу, что бы на одноядерном может не работать из за блокировок, а на многоядреном - будет работать (и похоже правильно). Обычно все как раз наоборот.

Comment: Говорят, ресурс неверно защищён критической секцией. Значит, как я понимаю, возможно некоторые критические секции тут и не нужны?

Comment: я думаю, что нужно, что бы изменения были "атомарные". К примеру, в самом конце 4 lock. Я честно бы их вынес в один большой lock. И ещё в двух местах.

Потом посмотрел, нет ли переменных, которые также могут модифицироваться с нескольких мест (запись в лог также бывает нужно завернуть в lock, так как она не атомарна).

Comment: (раскопки) Например, у вас не защищена переменная `m_ReadList.lst` в `ThreadProc`. Вы считываете `m_ReadList.lst.Count` _не_ под блокировкой, и затем индексируете `m_ReadList.lst` индексом, который сравнивается с длиной списка _до_ блокировки, а значит может быть уже недействительным.

Наверняка ещё есть ошибки, исправьте для начала эту.